# How Can I Easily Document a Database Environment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

HI Frdz, i have around 40 tables in database and i have created a document with all of these table names, fields, datatype, length of datatype, NUll or NOT NULL. but when i was working on tables in database i had to change the table field names, datatype and length of datatype as well. now as i am done with all my coding i have to have that document matching with what i have in database. so do u think is there any easy way i can do this or do i have to manually go through each table and update the doc?

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is an easier way, but what db are you using? E.g. Oracle, Sql Server 20xx, MySql etc.

Comment: Hi Thanks all of you. but i have to update that word doc with the database. isnt there something i can do like create a package and match fields from database put them in excel and then in word doc. my team leader wants me to do it manually but i think there should be any other way.

Comment: @Neooooooo you will spend more time making your custom package than it would take to just do it manually. **Listen to your boss!**

Comment: Thanks @JNK. i guess i have to do it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can usually query the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) tables for this kind of info.

E.g.,

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: I think this feature is datebase-dependend

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the database to Visio and get a nice database diagram out of it that way.   If they are the visual type that is.

Comment: I would love a little more info on this, I didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Here is a good article on how to make it work,  not great but since most users already have a visio license, it makes sense.   http://www.cbe.wwu.edu/misclasses/mis431s05/431ReverseEngineer.asp

Comment: Also could use Erwin database modeler is a commercial tool to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The [DBdesigner 4](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/) supports a approach to synchronize your entity relationship model and your real SQL table model. At the [features page](http://www.fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/features.php) they mention

- Model-To-Database syncronisation

I think this should be possible vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

```
select *
from user_tab_columns
```